# Where is the first time that Tehillim, Mishlei, Iyov are referred to as ספרי אמ"ת?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms, acronyms, job-iyov-book-of, mishlei

The books of Tehillim, Mishlei, Iyov are often referred as [ספרי אמ"ת](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9E%22%D7%AA). Where is the first source making this reference?

Comment: Treatises were written in the Middle Ages, maybe then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Chaim Shimon Neuhausen](https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?query=creator,contains,%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A2%D7%9F,%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F,%201872-1943&vid=NLI&lang=iw_IL&_gl=1*8sswdd*_ga*NjQ2NDg0Mjk3LjE1NTE5NTQyODY.*_ga_8P5PPG5E6Z*MTYyMzc0NzE5Mi40NDUuMC4xNjIzNzQ3MTk3LjU1&_ga=2.187222440.1203157458.1623747194-646484297.1551954286) in his essay "[תרגום אף ב"אמ"ת"](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58058&st=&pgnum=11)", [Otzar Hachaim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9A#%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F_%22%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%22), vol. 8, 1932, this acronym was created by the [Masoretes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretes), though he doesn't write which of the Masoretes was the first to do this.

[According](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38509&pgnum=122) to [Seligman Baer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seligman_Baer) and [Hermann Strack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Strack) in their edition of [Aharon ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_ben_Moses_ben_Asher)'s [Dikdukei Hate'amim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D), the expression "קבלה של אמת" used by ben Asher [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38509&pgnum=43) in reference to the Ketuvim may be an allusion to the ספרי אמ"ת. As his book was one of the very first Tanachic grammar works, it seems that this hint may be the first written usage of the acronym.